# Python Requests Login Automation

Tags: python, cookies, automation, python-requests

I am trying to use Python Requests to login to my UPS MyChoice account. Each page request has it's own `CSRFToken` value. I am trying to simulate this with Python Requests but I keep getting 403 Forbidden Error.

UPS does their login in a two-stage setup.. You enter username, make request, and then you enter password (using CSRFToken from previous request), and then login. I am unable to get past the step to enter username.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar() # Create cookie jar

# Go to home page to get init cookies
response = s.get("https://www.ups.com/us/en/Home.page", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'})
jar.update(response.cookies)

# Go to login page, update cookie jar, get CSRFToken
response = s.get("https://www.ups.com/lasso/login?loc=en_US&returnto=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ups.com%2Fus%2Fen%2FHome.page", headers=headers_main, cookies=jar)
jar.update(response.cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
csrftoken = soup.find(id='CSRFToken')['value']

url = "https://www.ups.com/lasso/login"

payload = f'CSRFToken={csrftoken}&loc=en_US&returnto=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ups.com%252Fus%252Fen%252FHome.page&forgotusername=YZ&connectWithSocial=YZ&userID=MYUSERNAME&getTokenWithPassword1=&ioBlackBox=&ioElapsedTime='
headers = {
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Origin': 'https://www.ups.com',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Referer': 'https://www.ups.com/us/en/Home.page',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

response = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, cookies=jar) # Returns 403
```

What am I doing wrong in my code? I am comparing the requests between Chrome DevTools and Python Requests and they see similar.

Comment: need to comply with the website. speak to the devs to find out what is needed.

Comment: @D.L There is nothing UPS offers for the usage I am looking for.